# A website to upload my ios app that anyone can download

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Hi there I am looking for a website to upload my ios app(with swift) there and get it's link so that anyone can download it through the link.
thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4):

### Sorry, no...

The only (legitimate) way to do this is via the Apple App Store.

There *may* be a way to do this for jailbroken devices but that would be off-topic (I believe) for AskDifferent.

Comment: And for distribution of source code there are Github, Gitlab and friends :-)

Comment: Jailbreaking and app sideloading itself is on-topic here; the issue is around piracy and sideloading paid apps for free, which would be off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

## Yes.

AltStore exists, and uses **completely legitimate methods**, as Apple allows normal users to sign apps for their own personal devices, with one caveat: it needs to re-sign apps every 7 days (through USB or LAN connection to a PC with a Windows/Linux server installed).

It is completely open source, licensed under the AGPLv3: https://github.com/rileytestut/AltStore

Comment: Don't you have to be setup as a developer with apple to do that?

Comment: Not being a developer I can't say for sure but this line from the AltStore GitHub page would seem to indicate so. Doesn't a signing certificate require (?) a valid, paid, developer account? "AltStore resigns apps with your personal development certificate..."

Comment: I have not paid Apple any sort of fee for any sort of developer account, and it works fine for me.

Comment: I believe that's where the 7-day certificate expiry comes from, the lack of a paid account.

Comment: You can also make source code available, and users can compile and install themselves.